# Computing the limit of the expectation of a function of a stochastic process (phew!)

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

I state my problem in a few lines then describe what I have already done.

I have a quite simple stochastic differential equation (SDE):

$dx=-2x \, dt+\sqrt{1-x^2} \, dW$ with $W$ a brownian.

I want to compute $\displaystyle{\lim_{t\to 0}}~\mathbb{E}\left[B_t\tanh\left(A_t\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}\right)|x(0)\right]$ and can't manage to do it.

I want to describe a given phenomenon obeying my SDE, thus the factors B_t and A_t will depend on $t$. This is to ensure that as I decrease the time increment $t$ through which I approximate my continuous phenomenom by a "discrete" growth rate, as one cannot differentiate a Brownian, I will converge towards a given value. It is equivalent to the normalisation having to be applied to a random walk diffusion coefficient when one wants to converge to the "underlying" brownian.   EDIT : $A_t\propto \sqrt{t}$ and $B_t \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}

This is my problem, any suggestions are welcome, below i expand on where I am, and how I approach the problem :

Let $\phi(x(t),t)$ be a twice differentiable function, Ito's lemma yields that if $\phi(x(t),t)$ is solution of : 
$$(1)~\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial t}-2x\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}+\frac{1-x^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2}=0\textrm{, with }\phi(x,0)=\Phi(x(0))\textrm{ as initial condition,}$$ then $\phi(x(t),t)=E[\Phi(x(0))|x(t)=x]$.

Noting that the partial differential equation (1) can be rewritten as $\partial_t\phi=M[\phi]$ with $M[.]$ a linear operator, any function of the form : $$\phi(x,t)=f(x)+\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}M^n[f]$$ is a solution to the PDE (1), satisfying the initial condition $\phi(x,0)=f(x)$.

Taking $\Phi(x(0))=x(0)$, for example, and with $t>0$, yields $$\mathbb{E}[x(t)|x(0)]=x(0)e^{-2t}$$ thus $\displaystyle{\lim_{t\to 0}}~\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}|x(0)\right]=-2x(0)$

My problem is that $B_t~tanh\left(A_t\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}\right)$ is undefined at $t=0$, thus I cannot use the same approach.

I tried to compute the characteristic function as i can compute all the moments, then Fourier-transform it to get the distribution, but it doesn't seem to give any meaningful result, which I guess comes from the fact that the distribution tends towards pathological functions (Dirac distributions) as $t\to 0$ thus I i am not allowed to switch the limit and the expectation operator anymore.

I can expand if need be, but i think I'll already be lucky if anyone read this far :).

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT

I also tried to Taylor expand the $tanh$ (not bothering about radius of convergence to start with) apply the expectation operator, which I can compute when applied to any power of $x$. By $b_{2n}$ I denote the coefficient of the Taylor expansion of $tanh$.
\begin{eqnarray} 
B_t\tanh\left(A_t\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}\right)&=&B_t\tanh\left(A_t\frac{\Delta x}{t}\right)\\
&=&B_t\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}}\Delta x^{2n-1}\\
&=&B_t\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}} \displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}x(0)^k x(t)^{2n-1-k}
\end{eqnarray}

For simplicity I denote $x(0)=x$ and $x(t)=x_t$, and I apply the expectation operator : 
$$B_t\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}} \displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}x^k \mathbb{E}[x(t)^{2n-1-k}|x]$$
\begin{eqnarray} 
=&B\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}}\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}x^k \displaystyle{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}}\frac{t^m}{m!}M^m[x^{2n-1-k}]\\
\end{eqnarray}
Moreover, computations give that  : 
$$\forall(n,k)\in\mathbb{N^2},~M^n(x^k)=\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}}\alpha_{i,n}(k)x^{2i+\delta_k}$$
with $\delta_k=0$ if $k$ is even, $\delta_k=1$ if not, 
$$\alpha_{i,n+1}(k)=\alpha_{i,n}(k)(2i^2+3i+\delta_k(2i+1))-\alpha_{i+1,n}(k)(2i^2+3i+\delta_k(2i+1))$$
and initial condition : $\alpha_{i,0}(k)=\delta_{i,\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}$, with $\delta_{i,j}$ Kronecker's symbol. We can rearrange the sum :

\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&B\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}}\displaystyle{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}}\frac{t^m}{m!}\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}x^k \displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}}\alpha_{i,m}(2n-1-k)x^{2i+\delta_{k+1}}\\
&=&B\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}}\displaystyle{\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}}\frac{t^m}{m!}\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}\displaystyle{\sum_{i=\lfloor k/2\rfloor}^{n-1}} x^{2i+1} \alpha_{i,m}(2n-1-k)
\end{eqnarray}

In addition $x^{2i+1}\alpha_{i,m}(k)$ is a polynomial in $k$ of degree $d\leq 2m$, therefore its sum over $i$ has a maximal degree of $2m$ too. This implies that $$\forall m< n, ~\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k}\displaystyle{\sum_{i=\lfloor k/2\rfloor}^{n-1}} x^{2i+1} \alpha_{i,m}(2n-1-k)=0$$
We are left with :
\begin{eqnarray}
S&=&B_t\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}b_{2n}\frac{A_t^{2n-1}}{t^{2n-1}}\displaystyle{\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}}\frac{t^m}{m!}\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}} x^{2i+1}\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{2i+1}}(-1)^k\binom{2n-1}{k} \alpha_{i-\lfloor k/2\rfloor,m}(2n-1-k)
\end{eqnarray}

If we take $A\propto t$ and $B\propto \frac{1}{t}$, as $t\to0$, only the term $n=1$ is kept, therefore we obtain a result linear in $x$, which is neglecting all the terms in $x$ coming from the term $M^n(x^k)$. If $A\propto \sqrt{t}$ and $B\propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ we keep all the terms $m=n$. This expansion reduces to $$S=\displaystyle{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}}(-1)^{k+1} a_k C^{2k+1}x(1-x^2)^k$$
where $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor ! \leq a_k \leq n!$ numerically (I calculated the first 100 terms...). Thus this expansion diverges.

This seems normal to me (now) because $tanh$ has a finite radius of convergence, and as $t\to 0$ when taking the expected value, $\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{t}}$ gets larger and larger for some values of $x_t$, those divergences are taken care of by the distribution of $x_t$ which converges to $0$, but the taylor expansion assumes that the argument of $tanh$ is bounded, which is not the case.

Comment: you must want the $|x(0)$ outside of the parens, also , I would like the $\frac 1t$ outside the parens beacause for small t (say $x(0) = 0$  $x(t)$ doesn't know it's not a brownian motion, so $\frac {x(t)} t$ is quite large.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the typos. As to your suggestion, I agree, this corresponds to taking $A\propto t$ and $B\propto \frac{1}{t}$.

Comment: This modifies the specification of the problem, but not its computability so far as i can tell : the $\lim$ and the $\mathbb{E}$ operator still do not commute.

Comment: If you move the $\frac 1t$ outside you are computing the generator.  With the $\frac 1t$ inside $tanh() \approx 1 $ or $-1$ depending on whether $x(t) > 0$ or not.  That is because $\frac {x(t)} t $ is large.

Comment: Could you expand/link as to what generator means in this context? As to $\frac{x(t)}{t}$ being large, actually I do not think it is a sufficient argument to consider $A\propto t$ and $B\propto \frac{1}{t}$. I might be wrong, but as the expectation is time dependent (i.e. the distribution of $x(t)$ depends on $t$ given the value of $x(0)$), the pathologies you describe could be "taken care of" by the distribution converging towards Dirac-like functions as $\frac{x(t)}{t}$ diverges, could they not? It seems to me that you implicitly switch the limit and the expectation, which I think is illicit

Comment: you can read about generators here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)

Comment: I think you have 2 B's, one brownian motion, one deterministic ?  If $A(t) \approx t$ the argument of tanh $ \rightarrow 0$, and if $A \approx 1$ I think the limit is 0, because $tanh() \approx 1_{x > x(0)} - 1_{x < x(0)}$, and it must be roughly symmetric.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the generator link, the f(.) cant depend explicitly on t unfortunately! I've made progress over the past few days, although I'm not done yet, I'll update the question over the weekend properly, but in the meantime, here goes : i have to take $A(t)\propto\sqrt{t}$ and $B(t)\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ for the expectation to converge as $t\to0$ while keeping the meaning of what I'm trying to capture. This comes from the properly calculated Taylor expansion, which I won't write in this comment (very large expression), but i'll update it in the text of the question.

Comment: And thanks for the 2 B's, i'll correct this immediately

Answer (score 3):

One could begin with the decomposition
$$
\frac{x(t)-x(0)}t=a(t)x(0)+b(t)y(0)W(t)+b(t)z(t),
$$
where
$$
a(t)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-2t}-1}t,\quad b(t)=\frac{\mathrm e^{-2t}}t,\quad y(s)=\mathrm e^{2s}\sqrt{1-x(s)^2}
$$
and
$$
z(t)=\int_0^t(y(s)-y(0))\mathrm dW(s).
$$
When $t\to0$, $a(t)\to-2$, $b(t)\sim1/t$, $W(t)=\sqrt{t}V$ where $V$ is standard normal, and $z(t)$ is centered normal with variance $O(t^2)$, hence
$$
\frac{x(t)-x(0)}t=y(0)\frac1{\sqrt{t}}V+U(t),
$$
where $U(t)$ is a family of random variables bounded in $L^2$. Now, for every function $u$ such that $|u(t)|\ll1/\sqrt{t}$ when $t\to0$,
$$
\tanh\left(A\left(y(0)\frac1{\sqrt{t}}V+u(t)\right)\right)\to\mathrm{sign}(AV).
$$
If made rigorous, all this would yield
$$
\mathbb E\left(\tanh\left(A\frac{x(t)-x(0)}t\right)\right)\to\mathbb E\left(\mathrm{sign}(AV)\right)=0.
$$
**Edit:** It appears that $A=A_t$ should depend on $t$, for example with $A_t\propto\sqrt{t}$. If $A_t=a\sqrt{t}+o(\sqrt{t})$, the above suggests that
$$
\mathbb E\left(\tanh\left(A_t\frac{x(t)-x(0)}t\right)\right)\to\mathbb E\left(\tanh\left(a\sqrt{1-x(0)^2}V\right)\right)=0.
$$
**Edit 2:** The decomposition we started with follows from Itô's formula since
$$
\mathrm d(\mathrm e^{2t}x(t))=2\mathrm e^{2t}x(t)\mathrm dt+\mathrm e^{2t}\mathrm dx(t)=y(t)\mathrm dW(t),
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm e^{2t}x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^ty(s)\mathrm dW(s),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
x(t)=\mathrm e^{-2t}x(0)+\mathrm e^{-2t}\int_0^ty(s)\mathrm dW(s),
$$
that is,
$$
x(t)-x(0)=(\mathrm e^{-2t}-1)x(0)+\mathrm e^{-2t}z(t)+\mathrm e^{-2t}y(0)W(t).
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can rewrite your decomposition as follows: $$\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}=\frac{E(x(t))-x(0)}{t}+\frac{E(x(t))}{x(0)t}\left(y(0)W(t)+ \int_0^t(y(s)-y(0))dW(s)\right)$$ I do not understand where it comes from. Could you give me a track to follow? Taking this formula as given for now, I am not sure I agree with your result. Firstly, in your last line you intervert the limit and the expectation operator, which I don't think is legit as the dominated convergence theorem would require to be able to find a function g dominating the distribution f(x,t) of x at t.

Comment: Secondly, as I was telling Mike a few weeks ago, the A and B factors depend on t. The idea being that were I to approximate the stochastic process by a random walk of time step t I would like to converge towards the underlying stochastic process, so I have to consider $A\propto\sqrt{t}$. In this case, I guess that instead of converging towards $sign(AV)$ the tangent converges towards an indefinite quantity, hence my problem.

Comment: The decomposition is straightforward from Itô's formula. Regarding your "Firstly", the domination is obvious since $|\tanh|\leqslant1$ uniformly.

Comment: Regarding your "Secondly", I did miss that $A$ and $B$ depend on $t$ (say, you should really write them $A_t$ and $B_t$, no?). Then the way $A_t$ depends on $t$ seems to be crucial--but I see nothing about that in your question.

Comment: We can express the expectation as $E(tanh(x,t))=\int_Rtanh(x,t)dF(x,t)$ (1) which is equivalent to $E(tanh(x,t))=\int_Rtanh(x,t)f(x,t)dx$ (2) with F the c.d.f and f the distribution. Correct me if i am wrong but dominated convergence requires domination (a) and a constant measure space (b). In (1) as you pointed out (a) is ok but (b) is violated, in (2) (b) is ok but (a) is violated.

Comment: As to the secondly, i did touch on it in my question but I agree that it is not as clearly presented as it should, apologies. It is evocated in the first paragraph and the third to last paragraph of the edit section. I will edit the question.

Comment: About domination, considering $\xi_t=\tanh(A_t(x(t)-x(0))/t)$, one sees that $|\xi_t|\leqslant1$ hence, if $\xi_t\to\xi$ almost surely, then $\mathbb E(\xi_t)\to\mathbb E(\xi)$ without further ado. (I do not know what your "constant measure space" refers to, sorry.)

Comment: Basically here the problem is that the expectation operator itself depends on t so that what you are doing comes down to : $\lim_{t\to0} E_t(tanh(x,t))=E_0(lim_{t\to0}(tanh(x,t))$. You are interverting the limit operator and implicitly distributing it.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: No, all the random variables may be defined on the same probability space hence there is no $\mathbb E_t$ depending on $t$. No implicit distribution here, whatever that means. (And I do not understand $\tanh(x,t)$, since the function $\tanh$ is defined on $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb R^2$.)

Comment: Ok so f(x,t) is not dominated, but being a probability distribution, one can take an integration by parts of expression (2) in my comment above to obtain a dominated integrand, thus allowing to switch the limit and expectation operators, you were right. Thanks a lot for your suggestions, as to the actual value of the expectation with $A_t\propto\sqrt{t}$ I am not sure it can be calculated... Cheers

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't seen your comment above, so my answer is kind of useless ^^. As to tanh(x,t) it was just a not very rigorous way of gaining some space, I agree tanh is on R, although through an Ito-like notation it could be formally considered a bivariate function, adding afterwards the fact that x=x(t). Anyways, interversion is ok as you noted. Thanks

Comment: As to your edit, could you explicit with respect to which variable V is standard normal? I guess it is normal in x(t) centered in x(0). For convenience we both have dropped that here $E(Z)$ is a shortcut for $E(Z|x(o))$, Z being whatever quantity, so isn't $E(tanh(a(\sqrt{1-x(0)^2}V)))=tanh(a(\sqrt{1-x(0)^2))}$? I have to go, i will come back in a few hours.

Comment: The formulations *with respect to which variable V is standard normal* and *normal in x(t) centered in x(0)* have no meaning that I am aware of. The object $V$ is a random variable with standard normal distribution. In particular, $\mathbb E(V)=0$ and $\mathbb E(V^2)=1$. // The suggestion that $\mathbb E(\tanh(\alpha V))=\tanh(\alpha V)$ for some real number $\alpha$ confuses a real number (the LHS) with a random variable (the RHS). // Some misunderstandings about the objects probability theory is concerned with, seem to be at play here but I am not able to pinpoint them more precisely.

Comment: Now now, from the bottom of my heart, I am deeply sorry for having understood your sentence "V is standard normal" as meaning that it was a gaussian function of some variable, but please, there is no need for despise. For one thing it makes you read too rapidly what I wrote: when saying that I confuse a real LHS and a random RHS, well, $x(0)$ is a known realisation of the random variable $x$ at date $0$, so $tanh(a\sqrt{1-x(0)^2})$ is real :-P. Anyways, now that I understand V as a random variable, I do agree that $E(tanh...)=0$ ^^.

Comment: However :D, I still have a few issues with a few things in what you wrote, which might be what is hidden in your "if made rigorous". For a start, indentifying with the terms in your first equation, $U(t)=a(t)x(0)+b(t)z(t)$ with $a(t)x(0)\to-2x(0)$ as $t\to 0$. But $\lim_{t\to 0} E(\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t})=-2x(0)$ so that I don't see how $u(t)<<1/\sqrt{t}$ as $t\to 0$. I might loose a subtelty when you go from U the family of random variables to u the function but it seems to me that in assuming that u goes to $0$, $-2x(0)$ were "forgotten".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7535/discussion-between-alexis-and-did)

Comment: Ok, in following what stackexchange suggests, namely avoiding extended discussions in comments, i invited you to the chat, which doesn't seem to support the TeX equations. You have much more experience than me on this website, I will continue here, because it seems to me to be much more convenient, but let me know if you consider it is better to move to the chat.

Comment: $dx=-2xdt+\sqrt{1-x^2}dW$, so: $\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}=-2\frac{\int_0^t x(s) ds}{t}+\frac{\int_0^t\sqrt{1-x(s)^2}dW(s)}{t}$ which I fail to identify to your first equation. Considering $f(x,t)=\frac{x-x(0)}{t}$ Ito's lemma yields $d\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t}=(-\frac{x(t)-x(0)}{t^2}-\frac{2x}{t})dt+\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{t}dW_t$ but this cannot be integrated between $0$ and $t$ because $f(x,t)$ is not twice differentiable in $x$ and $t$, so in fact Ito's lemma can't be applied http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D%27s_lemma. So I still don't get how it is straightforward from Ito's formula.

Comment: I might fail to see things that are obvious to you, but i posted this question to understand.

Comment: OK, I have a suggestion, and I would like you to consider it seriously: please spend more time trying to understand what is written and working on it before jumping to the conclusion that something must be wrong. (Anyway I cannot continue forever to debunk the issues you have with what I write which seem to come partly from the fact that you read too quickly.) For instance... if one writes down explicitely $U(t)$ (which I omitted since I thought my post was already pretty explicit), one sees indeed a contribution $-2x(0)$. This is $O(1)$ hence $\ll1/\sqrt{t}$. .../...

Comment: .../... Note that $-2x(0)$ is not the main contribution to $U(t)$, but that the goal is to prove that all of them are $\ll1/\sqrt{t}$. To sum up, nobody said that $U(t)$ goes to $0$, and $-2x(0)$ was not "forgotten", thank you. More subtle but also explicit in my post is the fact that the control "$U(t)$ bounded in $L^2$" (or "$\sqrt{t}U(t)$ bounded"?) should ensure that $U(t)$ does not appear in the limit. This, I did not completely check (and I said I did not). (As an aside, to put a link to the WP page on Itô's lemma for my attention is... sweet.)

Comment: Thank you for your time Did, I did read your contributions too quickly. As for the result, as I was saying before, $B_t$ depends on t too, $B_t\propto\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ so this brings back an indetermination. For this reason, I don't think the answer to my question is computable, I am thinking about closing the question. I saw it was considered as drastic, I would like to have your opinion (if you see that in assuming the answer is not computable I am mistaken, do not spend more time explaining, just say so and i will leave the question open). Thanks again and my apologies.